# Mostrar el mensaje completo de un readonly field en django Admin

Tags: python, django

Estoy teniendo problemas para modificar la interfaz del panel de admin en Django, cree una app para que los usuarios puedan mandar mensajes a traves de un formulario, estos mensajes se leen en el panel de administrador, pero el contenido del mensaje no se esta mostrando por completo, al llegar al limite horizontal simplemente no se ve el resto del mensaje una linea por debajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu problema, quieres un Textarea. en teoría hay un tipo de dato para esto "TextField", todo esta documentado aqui:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField

es simplemente cambiar el modelo de CharField a TextField y te aparecerá la Textarea.

Comment: En el modelo el mensaje ya corresponde a un textfield, creo que el problema esta en el panel de admin de django que aplica todo el mensaje en una sola linea

Comment: Si le intentas poner este widget=forms.Textarea al modelo ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/